# get link from wp_get_attachment_url(); in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a hyperlink on some text within my Wordpress gallery thumbnail but I don't know how to pull out the hyperlink from `wp_get_attachment_link($id);` Maybe using preg_replace or something?

I'm currently using the WP Gallery Custom Links plugin to add custom links to my thumbnail images so that stops me using `wp_get_attachment_url($id);` l as that just displays the image location.

Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work with my WP Gallery Custom Links plugin

Comment: Don't get it at all, just tried to give you the right direction for this. I have no idea what you are doing, anyways.

Comment: Sorry thats because I wrote the wrong thing, I've amended it now